# Color a un alert

Tags: javascript, html

quisiera saber que forma hay de que el texto dentro de un alert, aparezca en un color determinado, por ejemplo amarillo. todo esto desde un .js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
  alert("amarillo")
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente **no es posible**.

Los `alert`, `prompt` y `confirm` son creados por el navegador y sus estilos visuales dependen enteramente de éste. El método `alert()` de **JavaScript**, específicamente hablando, acepta únicamente una cadena y la procesa usando un widget nativo. No hay forma para darle estilo.

Por otro lado, hay muchos plugins que te permiten crear una ventana de notificación completamente personalizable. Con gusto te detallo algunas muy populares:

**Bootbox**:
[GitHub](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox)

**Toastr**:
[GitHub](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)

**SweetAlert**:
[Page/GitHub](https://sweetalert2.github.io)

**AlertifyJS**:
[GitHub](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/AlertifyJS)